# the error in my code is "Uncaught TypeError: toggleButton.addEventListener is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am coding interactive nav bar and face me this error "script.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: toggleButton.addEventListener is not a function" and i don't know how to fix it

```
var toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')

var navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

to display the nav bar

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return an array so in your case you are adding an event listener on array instead of an targeted element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < toggleButton.length; i++) {
    toggleButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
    });
}
```

If you have ES6 support you can replace it with this:

```
Array.from(toggleButton).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
});
```

Also please refer this:
[Element.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)